# Link an Issue to another Issue of type 'Test' in JIRA using API

Tags: api, hyperlink, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create an issue of type 'Test' in JIRA using API.
I am able to create new Issue, but when I try to link an issue either while creating or updating (POST or PUT respectively) I get error response.

Here is my request and response:

**REQUEST**

```
{
    "fields": {
        "project": {
            "key": "TGX",
            "name": "TGX"
        },
        "summary": "Test JIRA API to Create an Issue",
        "description": "",
        "assignee": {
            "name": "firstname.lastname"
        },
        "customfield_10513": "/Finance/Sprint 4/TGX-515",
        "issuetype": {
            "name": "Test",
            "description": "Represents a Test"
        },
        "priority": {
            "name": "Medium"
        },
        "update": {
            "issuelinks": [{
                "add": {
                    "type": {
                        "name": "Tests",
                        "inward": "is tested by",
                        "outward": "test"
                    },
                    "outwardIssue": {
                        "key": "TGX-515",
                        "fields": {
                            "summary": "Test"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        "components": [{
            "name": "Finance Module",
            "description": "finance, budgeting and audit"
        }]
    }
}
```

**RESPONSE**

```
{
    "errorMessages": [],
    "errors": {
        "update": "Field 'update' cannot be set. It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown."
    }
}
```

If I use 'add' instead of 'update' in the request, I get similar error message.
I am using Xray plugin in JIRA for test management.

Answer (score 2):

In order to update an issue, your JSON must look like this:

```
{
  "fields": {...},
  "update": {...}
}
```

The JSON nesting is wrong in your case. You have put the `update` field below the `fields` in your JSON. This is the reason the error message tells you `Field 'update' cannot be set` because there is no such field with this name. For further details, please carefully read the [Jira REST API docs](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/#api-rest-api-3-issue-issueIdOrKey-put).